# how to log off from samba server on windows 10

Tags: windows, server

I have access to a Samba server using a username and password. To logging the server on windows 10, I put its IP address on the RUN and then input my username and password. Then I can access the data stored in the server normally. However, I don't know how to log off (or Sign out) from that server.

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwM9RaemCvE) tutorial about how to access the server, but it does not mention the log off process. I need to log-off and log-in again with my username and password whenever I need to access the server.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

Open CMD, type `NET USE X: /DELETE` or `NET USE \\SERVER\SHARENAME /DELETE`

where X: is your drive and \SERVER\SHARENAME your fully qualified share name.

### Step by Step

1. View all network connections:
2. `NET USE`

Example Output:

```
  Status                 Local       Remote            Network
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK                                 \\name\IPC$       Microsoft Windows Network
OK                                 \\name2\folder    Microsoft Windows Network
```

3. Using the Remote name, we can disconnect using on of the following statements, depending on which one we want to disconnect from:
4. `net use \\name /delete`

OR

`net use \\name2\folder /delete`

Example Output: (given the above \name\IPC being connected))

```
Net use  \\name /delete
\\name was deleted successfully.
```

Another way, to disconnect from every share is to execute `net use * /delete`. This will disconnect every Network share you're currently connected to. This is still quicker than logging off and back on.

### Bonus: make a script to do it

If you want to create an icon to automatically disconnect all network shares (using a GUI method), you can do the following:

1. Right-click on a blank area of the folder you want to add the shortcut to.
2. Point to New->Shortcut and click.
3. Type `net use * /delete /y` for the Command, then click Next.
4. Give it a name, and click Finish.

You can also specify a certain network share, if known in advance, and use that one instead. Using the /y automatically select the yes option in the command.

open notepad:

```
@echo off
::Disconnect user
net use * /delete /y
msg * /time:5 "You have been successfully Disconnected"
```

Copy paste save as a bat (file Extention " *.bat ", create a shortcut edit the shortcut to an icon of your choosing...
upon double click, the command will be run and a gui popup box will say the message and go away in 5 seconds or wait 5 seconds till appearing...
we use this quite a bit at work :)

Comment: I have executed the `/delete`, and `net use` is now an empty list ...but I can still access the share

Comment: I had exact same issue as BlueChip but with more research found this https://serverfault.com/questions/213765/how-do-i-remove-login-credentials-for-a-network-location-in-win7 which contains similar suggestions except one which was  @rocketsarefast suggestion with minor alteration which is from cmd to do the usual net use * /d then try to login as a different valid user  then do net use * /d again and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

"Try to restart your workstation".